# A simple case: detect keypress on a specific text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two text input fields:

```
Name:<input id="name" type="text" value="" name="username">
Age:<input id="age" type="text" value="" name="userage">
```

When user input `name` and press "Enter" key, I would like an alert window pop up.
When user input `age` and press "Enter" key, nothing happen.

To achieve above simple case described, I did the following jQuery code:

```
$("#name"),keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter on Name field!');
    }
})
```

You can also try the code out on [jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/sajdZ/1/).

However, when I input name and press enter, the alert window does not pop up, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo. You put a comma instead of a dot

```
$("#name").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter on Name field!');
    }
})
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stulentsev/sajdZ/2/).